# jquery get value from url then re-order divs

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to grab a parameter from a url for example.

www.x.com/?source=display&zone=lc&topic=cloud

So, If the topic is 'cloud', which it is then I want to re order 3 separate div's.

This is what I have so far in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.search.indexOf('topic=cloud') > -1) {
    alert('track present');
    $(".one").insertAfter(".two");
} else {
    $(".two").insertAfter(".three");
    alert('track not here');
}
</script>
```

and html is like this:

```
<div class="one">seo</div>
<div class="two">cloud</div>
<div class="three">social</div>
```

I get the alert, but when i use `.insertAfter();`

i get nothing

Answer (score 2):

If you can also use PHP - and according to your tags you can - I would prefer doing this in PHP, so no client side action is needed. Basically:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['topic']) && 'cloud' == $_GET['topic']) { ?>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two">cloud</div>
    <div class="three">social</div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="one">seo</div>        
    <div class="three">social</div>
    <div class="two">cloud</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This seems better than inserting them in the wrong order initially, better to do it right the first time than to fix it later

Comment: Agreed. Why pass on to the client what can be accomplished at the server? Older/slower/JS-disabled browsers will appreciate it coming from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use document ready and your code will do what you expect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { //<-- you are missing this

if (window.location.search.indexOf('topic=cloud') > -1) {
    alert('track present');
    $(".one").insertAfter(".two");
} else {
    $(".two").insertAfter(".three");
    alert('track not here');
}

}); // <-- and the closing element
</script>
```

---

The following works fine, try it and see how it compares to your code (also read Juan Mendes comment as he explains what is going on):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {  
        if (window.location.search.indexOf('topic=cloud') > -1) {
            alert('track present');
            $(".one").insertAfter(".two");
        } else {
            $(".two").insertAfter(".three");
            alert('track not here');
        }    
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="one">seo</div>
  <div class="two">cloud</div>
  <div class="three">social</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explanation: OP's code is trying to run before the HTML is parsed, therefore `$('.one')` and `$('.two')` don't exist at that moment. This is one of the reasons I don't like jQuery, no error when calling a method on an empty collection hides a lot of errors

Comment: I've updated to this. And still no re-ordering of my divs, anything I could be forgetting?

Comment: OK I fixed my issue, I was initializing cycle before i ordered the divs. I put my order code before cycle was initialized, so my divs got reordered first then cycle ran smooth

Comment: Thanks guys, one more question, what If i wanted to check the if against all three scenarios? seo, social, or cloud

Comment: I would try a switch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting an error related to jQuery's `$` not yet defined. Look in FireBug or Web Developer tools to check. Up until that line, you have not referenced jQuery `$` so no error is thrown.

**Possibility 1:** Make sure you have included jQuery on the page.

Something like this if local:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

Something like this if using CDN (hosted) version:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**Possibility 2:** Make sure you have included jQuery BEFORE you reference `$`. Move your `<script>` include above the rest of your scripting.

**Possibility 3:** If you are using another library like Prototype, reference `jQuery` directly (instead of `$`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.search.indexOf('topic=cloud') > -1) {
    alert('track present');
    jQuery(".one").insertAfter(".two"); // note jQuery, not $
} else {
    jQuery(".two").insertAfter(".three"); // note jQuery, not $
    alert('track not here');
}
</script>
```